# Finding slant asymptote

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am given a definition in my book.

Graph of function $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has slant or oblique asymptote $y=kx +l$ in $+\infty$, if

**1.** $\langle a,+\infty \rangle \subseteq I$ for some $a\in I$,
**2.** $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}f'(x)=k\in \mathbb{R}$
**3.**$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} (f(x)-kx)=l \in \mathbb{R}$

I don't understand **1.** and **2.** statement at all. Why are we even observing $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and why it has to be equal to $f'(x)$. **3.** I understand because by definition it has to be $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} (f(x)-(kx+l))=0$.

Comment: The condition $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}f'(x)=k\in \mathbb{R}$ is **not** necessary to guarantee the asymptote $y=kx +l$ when $x\to+\infty$. What is your source?

Comment: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~guljas/skripte/MATANALuR.pdf , it is page 114 in book(not in pdf), horizontalnu ili kosu means slant or oblique. Please correct it if it isn't correct @Did

Comment: If they ask that the derivative converges then indeed they are unnecessarily demanding. Condition 2. should read: $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=k\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out. @Did can i get your skype or something, i need some help with my exam. Where are you from btw? I am from Croatia as you can see

Comment: Sorry but no. $ $

Answer (score 1):

For 1:

I just think it is saying that $I$ has to contain an interval with no upper bound (otherwise the limits of $f$ as $x\to\infty$ do not make sense).

---

For 2:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=k+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-kx}{x}$$

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty} [f(x)-kx]=l$ by $3$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=k.$$

Geometrically $f(x)/x$ is the slope of a ray from the origin through $(x,f(x))$. Clearly as $x\to\infty$ the slope of the ray has to approach the slope of the slant asymptote (just as the slope of $f$ itself has to approach the slope of the asymptote).

Comment: Thank you. But when i compute slant asymptote i don't use $f'(x)$. I evaluate $f(x)/x$ limit and i get $k$. Then i search for $l$.

Comment: 2 just states that both limits give you $k$. You can then find $l$ using 3.